# Firebase storage: Return URLs in the same order as ordered files

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I am developing a web app on Firebase and am writing a function to upload to Firebase Storage and return the download URLs for the files the user uploads. The files have order and my intention is to store the URLs in the files' order. 
The below function returns URLs, but they are not in the intended order. I guess this has to do with different file sizes and different times it takes to upload each of them and download the link. 
How do I make sure that the URLs are stored in the promise in the intended order? e.g. I can think of invoking storageRef.put method only after the URL of the previous file is stored in the promise, but I am new to programming and don't know how to fix it...please help out!

```
function url_array_get(){
    const promises = [];
    const user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const filez=review_photo.files;
    const files=Array.from(filez); //This is an array of files with specific ordering
    files.forEach(function(file) { //The files are uploaded in the intended order
       let storageRef=firebase.storage().ref('data/'+user.uid+'/posts/'+file.name);
         promises.push(
             storageRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot){
                 return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
             })
         )
    })
    return Promise.all(promises); //The returned URLs are not in the intended order
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the order is wrong?  Can you post some evidence?  This code looks to me like it preserves the order between the files array and the downloadURLs.  I can see a way to make it neater (by using map instead of forEach and by factoring the put into a separate function), but I think you're wrong about it being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take advantage of the fact that, with [`Promise.All()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), "returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order".

By using `Promise.all()` twice, you will reach your goal. The following should do the trick (untested).

```
function url_array_get() {

    const filesPromises = [];
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const filez = review_photo.files;
    const files = Array.from(filez); //This is an array of files with specific ordering

    const urlsPromises = [];

    files.forEach(function (file) { //The files are uploaded in the intended order
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('data/' + user.uid + '/posts/' + file.name);

        filesPromises.push(
            storageRef.put(file)
        )
    })
    return Promise.all(filesPromises)
        .then(function (uploadTasks) {

            uploadTasks.forEach(function (uploadTask) {
                urlsPromises.push(uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
            })

            return Promise.all(urlsPromises)
        })
        .then(function (urls) {

            // urls is the Array of all download URLs in the right order
            urls.forEach(function (url) {
                console.log(url);
            })

        })

}
```

Comment: @J.Ko Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed answer?